# Bootstrap Dropdown CSS Clicked Color

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

[What my dropdown looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oIyA.png) when I click it changes to white.

[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZihE.png) The background is white and should be a lighter shade of blue that way the white text is readable.

I have tried updating the CSS with anything that contains dropdown or .open with a white color to a different one. No luck.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">
                    <span class="icon-bar">
                <asp:Image ID="logo" runat="server" Height="30px" ImageUrl="" Width="35px" />
                </span>DT</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="">Reporting</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Help">Help</a></li>
                    <li class="dropwdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Views<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="">Funnel Mgmt</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="">Global Deal</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="">Regional Deal</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a runat="server" href="">Admin</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="">Resources</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**The CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-header {
    border-color: #080808;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
    background-color: #080808;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #9d9d9d;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #080808;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #444444;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mario, welcome to Stack Overflow. The code you provided doesn't reproduce the layout in your screenshot. Please give us the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the actual problem that you need help with.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you with CSS, you will need to provide your CSS in addition to your HTML; we can't reproduce your problem without it. Please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I think I included enough to reproduce the full menu

Comment: Tried taking the "w" out, good eye! Did not fix the white clicked option I'm having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, the CSS you quoted doesn't match the blue colouring shown in the example image. I've attempted to reproduce this (see notes in the CSS below), but I think the style rule you're after is:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(74, 201, 255, 1);
}
```

Obviously, change the `rgba()` value to match your preferred colour.  Note that you may need to click 'Full page' after clicking 'Run snippet' below, otherwise the 'small viewport' Bootstrap media query is likely to kick in and alter the menu appearance.

```css
/* only required to reproduce blue background for the demo */
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: rgba(0, 150, 214, 1) !important;
    margin-top: 4em; /* additional spacing to avoid StackOverflow menu bar in 'full page' view */
}

/* only required to reproduce white text for the demo */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
     color: #fff !important;
}

/* ensure background colour for open dropdown menu is a lighter blue colour */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
    /* white text */
    color: #fff;
    
    /* NB: '!important' is only required for the demo,
           due to the order in which CSS rules are applied.
           You should be able to update this to the following
           which should still work:
           
           background-color: rgba(74, 201, 255, 1);
           */
    background-color: rgba(74, 201, 255, 1) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">
                    <span class="icon-bar">
                <asp:Image ID="logo" runat="server" Height="30px" ImageUrl="" Width="35px" />
                </span>DT</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="">Reporting</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Help">Help</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Views<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="">Funnel Mgmt</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="">Global Deal</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="">Regional Deal</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a runat="server" href="">Admin</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="">Resources</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That was just what I needed. Thank you Conan!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is supposed to be like that, but you have a:

`<li class="dropwdown">`

over there, and you haven't any "dropwdown" class :)